# How to set access control allow origin on particular file web.config

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis, config

If this were a dynamic response, I'd simply do `Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");` but I have a static file I'd like to allow cross domain access to.

Is there a way to assign this header to a particular file just using web.config? Say it's just example.com/flat.json

I guess I could route the file to dynamic page, but that would be a bit silly.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

This should work

```
<location path="Sample.txt">
    <system.webServer>
      <httpProtocol>
        <customHeaders>
          <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
        </customHeaders>
      </httpProtocol>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
```

Comment: Ah yes, always forget about the location element.

Comment: hi, after I added the location element i stopped being able to download it. If i make a request from my browser to this file, it says 404 the directory can not be found.

Comment: What if I want certain web to call it?

Comment: Hi @Si8, you can modify the value property of the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header to allow certain website to have access. For more details see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10636611/how-does-access-control-allow-origin-header-work

Comment: why location element is important here? Please help me to understand

Comment: Hi @JeyaSuriyaMuthumari - Because you want to allow cross-domain access only for the specific file mentioned in the location path attribute. If you don't use location element here, the cross domain access will be open for everything.