# FontAwesome only displays 'sometimes' in IE9

Tags: internet-explorer, cross-browser, font-awesome

I am trying to replace my image based icons with [FontAwesome](http://fortawesome.github.com/Font-Awesome/)'s custom icon font.  I found this [FontAwesome WordPress plugin](https://github.com/rachelbaker/Font-Awesome-WordPress-Plugin) that does it for me.  All the icons display properly on the following:

- OSX Google Chrome 24.0.1312.52
- OSX Apple Safari 6.0.2
- OSX running a Windows XP VM using Internet Explorer 8.0.6001

However, the icons do NOT display on the following:

- OSX Mozilla FireFox 18.0
- Windows 7 running IE9
- Any of [SauceLabs](https://saucelabs.com/account)' Internet Explorer VMs

I checked to see if the page is accidentally being rendered in quirks mode and it is not.  I am at a loss as to what the problem could be.  Can someone please help me out here???

Please view my website that is having the problem [here](http://aashtowarebridge.com/).
I've setup a clean test page [here](http://aashtowarebridge.com/font/) that DOES appear to work, which makes me think another plugin is messing with my site making the icons not appear.

**EDIT:** I believe I have discovered the problem.  From my understanding, IIS7 servers do not understand .WOFF files as detailed [here](http://www.dirigodev.com/blog/404-errors-in-IIS7-for-embedded-woff-font-files/).  So I tried uploading the .WOFF file to another non-IIS7 server, only to find out that Mozilla Firefox doesn't allow fonts to be loaded from a separate server.  So, basically, I must have the font on my IIS7 server.  I have since instant messaged our IT guy, but have not heard back from him.

Answer (score 0):

I FIGURED IT OUT ON MOZILLA!  Internet Explorer is still not working.

- My website is hosted on an IIS7 server. IIS7 servers don't recognize .WOFF fonts (without changing some settings).
- So I tried hosting the .WOFF file on a non-IIS7 server.  However, Mozilla FireFox doesn't allow fonts to be loaded from a separate server.
- All you must do is edit the *web.config* file to look like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13061524/how-to-set-access-control-allow-origin-on-particular-file-web-config) to enable loading fonts from a separate server.