# changing the Access-Control-Allow-Origin to allow Jquery load() to work

Tags: jquery, ajax, cors

**SITUATION:**

- Internal web site running off a web server.
- SharePoint running off a different internal web server.
- It's all internal, and all on the same `company.com` internal domain (different sub domains because they are accessed via `SharePoint.company.com` and `internalWeb.company.com`)

**PROBLEM:**

- XMLHttpRequest cannot load `http://SharePoint.company.com.` Origin `http://internalWeb.company.com` is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

**WHAT I WANT:**

- Use ajax and the JQuery load() function from my web sites running off
  the web server to call urls on the SharePoint server.

**NOTE:**

- This seems like it should be possible to set the SharePoint server to
  allow cross origin requests by just setting the
  Access-Control-Allow-Origin, it's **ALL INTERNAL** and I can change the web.configs or IIS settings as I please
- Is this possible? If so, where do I set it. I have read a lot on this
  and can't seem to get a clear answer.

**CODE:** (on my web page running on `internalWeb.company.com`)

```
$("#details").load("SharePoint.company.com/someDetails.html");
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A quick fix could be to set a custom header in your SharePoint web.config:

http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/httpprotocol/customheaders

```
<customHeaders>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
</customHeaders>
```

Or for just that domain, try

```
<customHeaders>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="http://internalWeb.company.com" />
</customHeaders>
```

Comment: Does this have to go under a `location` tag? r just under the regular `system.webserver` section?

Comment: It can, I don't think it needs to. Here's an example with the location tag: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13061524/how-to-set-access-control-allow-origin-on-particular-file-web-config

Comment: Open your network tab, look at the xhr request, and see if the header is actually being returned.

Comment: I don't see it in the Header, but isn't that the header that the web page is sending TO the second server?

Comment: The `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header should be a _response_ header.

Comment: I think I'm at the end of my knowledge on the subject without doing more research myself. I would recommend editing your question with your new information and adding a few tags related to web.config and asp.net, or asking a new question with the more specific info.

Comment: OK, ignore my past few comments. I was putting it in the wrong place. I'm seeing the Header come back. However, now I'm getting a 401 error. Something I need to do to tell the ajax request to the user's windows credentials along?

Comment: Maybe you need something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1002179/how-can-i-pass-windows-authentication-to-webservice-using-jquery

Comment: I had to add `<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" value="true" />` to my web.config and `xhrFields: { withCredentials: true }` to my ajax request. HOWEVER, using `*` for `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` you cannot use `withCredentials:true`. SOOOO I guess I have to specify the servers individually :) Thanks for your help. And of course, from what I'm reading, none of this will work with IE8/9

Comment: No problem. I haven't used it, but there is a CORS support library for IE8 out there you might look into.

Comment: So actually, this isn't really doing what I wanted. I had to use $.ajax rather than .load(), so now instead of loading the page into the div, I'm just getting the html back. I want to load it into the div.

Comment: `$.ajax(...).done(function(result) { $('#details').html(result); });`

Comment: ya, i tried that, however, it gives me a bunch of errors because it can't load the css and javascript files etc.