# Need to add a key to allowed origins key in web.config file

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, web-config

I've been looking all through Stackedoverflow and other sites but can't seem to figure out how to do this.  I want to add a web address to my web.config allowed origins key.  But How do I do this?

I am working on this part of the below web address:

> "If you look into Retail Server's log you will see a corresponding  error "The >requested resource does not support http method 'OPTIONS". To fix it open Retail >Server's web.config, locate there a key AllowedOrigins and add there the url >corresponding to your dev version of Cloud POS - >https://RetailPosFromSdk.cloudax.dynamics.com if you are following the above >example. Then save the file and click Retry in Cloud POS. Now you should be able >to select the Store, Register and Device - basically the same experience when >you use Prod version of your Cloud POS."

https://community.dynamics.com/ax/b/axforretail/archive/2016/06/25/how-to-run-cloud-pos-from-retail-sdk

Comment: As I have looked into this I haven't found anything that is truly helpful.  I have found some references to "CORS" is this related to AllowedOrigins?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors

Comment: And this is the file I've been trying to use to do this but can't seem to figure it out.  How do I add a AllowedOrigin to a web.config file?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api#set-the-allowed-origins

Comment: Colleague gave me this stackoverflow to use:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13061524/how-to-set-access-control-allow-origin-on-particular-file-web-config